# :hover на li в котором содержится svg и параграф

Tags: html, css, scss, hover

помогите разобраться,
я совсем зелёный,
прошу словами не кидаться :)

Ситуация такая: Есть ненумерованный список, в нём, в каждом из пунктов лежит  и ссылка .
Проблема: Когда я вешаю hover на li , ничего не работает, когда вешаю hover на ссылку или на span изменяется либо ссылка либо span. Мне же нужно, что бы при наведении на пункт li изменялся и span и ссылка. Подскажите, как заставить их одновременно изменяться?
И ещё один нюанс, в спане у меня находится svg иконка, точнее её класс который импортируется из файла scss.

```html
<nav class="sidebar-links">
  <ul>
    <li class="sidebar-links__link">
      <span class="v-icon-home"></span>
      <p>Главная</p>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-links__link">
      <span class="v-icon-about"></span>
      <p>Обо мне</p>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-links__link">
      <span class="v-icon-services"></span>
      <p>Услуги</p>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-links__link">
      <span class="v-icon-portfolio"></span>
      <p>Портфолио</p>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-links__link">
      <span class="v-icon-blogs"></span>
      <p>Блог</p>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-links__link">
      <span class="v-icon-contacts"></span>
      <p>Написать мне</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

```css
li {
  &:hover {
    color: #5AB159;
  }
}
```

На всякий случай приложу откуда импортируется svg

```scss
%icon-standard {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  mask-position: center;
  -webkit-mask-position: center;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-size: contain;
  -webkit-mask-size: contain;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;

  &:hover {
    background-color: #5AB159;
  }
}

.v-icon {
  &-about {
    @extend %icon-standard;
    mask-image: url("../resources/img/nav-icons/about.svg");
    -webkit-mask-image: url("../resources/img/nav-icons/about.svg");
  }

  &-blogs {
    @extend %icon-standard;
    mask-image: url("../resources/img/nav-icons/blogs.svg");
    -webkit-mask-image: url("../resources/img/nav-icons/blogs.svg");
  }

  &-contacts {
    @extend %icon-standard;
    mask-image: url("../resources/img/nav-icons/contacts.svg");
    -webkit-mask-image: url("../resources/img/nav-icons/contacts.svg");
  }

  &-home {
    @extend %icon-standard;
    mask-image: url("../resources/img/nav-icons/home.svg");
    -webkit-mask-image: url("../resources/img/nav-icons/home.svg");
  }

  &-portfolio {
    @extend %icon-standard;
    mask-image: url("../resources/img/nav-icons/portfolio.svg");
    -webkit-mask-image: url("../resources/img/nav-icons/portfolio.svg");
  }

  &-services {
    @extend %icon-standard;
    mask-image: url("../resources/img/nav-icons/services.svg");
    -webkit-mask-image: url("../resources/img/nav-icons/services.svg");
  }

}
```

Заранее благодарю за уделённое время! Вопрос глупенький, но моих мозгов уже не хватает :)

Comment: Не нужно издеваться над пользователем. Делай так, чтобы :hover стоял на ссылке.

Comment: Хм, а вот об этом я что то не подумал( Попробую накинуть на сслку :)

Comment: Попробовал, не работает))

Comment: Ну так если не работает, то надо другие стили поменять, чтобы заработало. Кликабельная область ссылки должна совпадать с областью подсветки при наведении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При добавлении ховера для тега `li` дочерний элемент (тег `p`) не наследует цвет от родителя, потому что вероятнее всего дочерний элемент уже имеет свойство `color`, которое является более приоритетным. Чтобы избежать этого, дочернему элементу необходимо явно задать цвет.

Для добавления стилей при ховере двум дочерним элементам вам поможет следующий селектор:

```css
li {
  &:hover {
    p {
      color: #5AB159;
    }

    span {
      // необходимые стили
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Вот! Спасибо, я был уверен что hover можно вешать только на один элемент, то есть, был уверен что в hover пишутся только стили , а не селекторы. Спасибо, теперь запомню навсегда :)

Answer (score 1):

Вбейте в голову, что если нужно применить эффект ко всем элементам внутренним - нужно псевдо-классы давать их родителю и у вас в будущем не будет проблем.
Я даже ниже привёл пример того, как вы это реализовывали, что бы вы почувствовали разницу
Когда наводите перекрашиваются оба элемента, но трансформация текста происходит только там, куда вы направите курсор.

```css
li span {
  color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  display: block;
}
li a {
  color: blue;
}
li:hover span {
  color: red;
}
li:hover a {
  color: red;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
}

li span:hover {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
li a:hover {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="sidebar-links__link">
    <span class="v-icon-home">Типо SVG картинка</span><br>
    <a href="#">Главная</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный разбор! Я вообще не в ту сторону думал.